# Puppeteer FileChooser throwing "TypeError: undefined is not a function" ??? when trying to open the FileChooser to upload an IMG

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

I'm currently trying to upload an image using Puppeteer, however when I try to open the FileChooser:

*Y'all know this guy*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRApS.png
*This is an example image*

to browse and select a file, I get the following error in my console

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and then a timeout error which is expected

```
TimeoutError: waiting for waiting for file chooser failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

The question would be... Why undefined? Where I went wrong? Here's my code:

```
const [fileChooser] = Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  page.click("input#EventImage"),
]);
await fileChooser.accept([
  __dirname + "/screenshot.png",
]);
```

*Everything else before this is working just fine*

*Puppeteer version: 3.1.0*

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I did this and succeeded:

```
await page.waitForSelector("selector");
const input = await page.$("selector");
await input.uploadFile(filepath);
```

I'd prefer the `fileChooser` syntax, but seems like the workaround for other people is to downgrade the puppeteer version. I did not wanted to, so I decided to take this path from above.